# How did people cut "pieces of eight"?

Tags: spanish-empire, currency, numismatics

The Spanish silver peso was a very common coin consisting of "fine quality silver, assayed at .931 or .916," [according to CoinWeek](https://coinweek.com/world-coins/history-of-coins-two-bits-four-bits-six-bits-eight/). Under some circumstances one peso coins, worth eight *reales*, [would be cut into slivers to separate those *reales* from each other](https://books.google.com/books?id=mrmWA14x52AC&lpg=PA123&ots=HYxyCfvF5l&dq=cut%20reales%20common&pg=PA123#v=onepage&q&f=false). While some sources downplay the coin cutting, saying it's held to have been more common than it truly was, it clearly happened.

How did people cut the coins? Did this require going to a blacksmith, or were they soft enough to snip or chop up with household tools?

[image: 4 reales]

Comment: Some surviving examples don't seem to have nearly as clean edges as this one here. This seems to indicate people were cutting coins with household tools, since silver is after all much softer than steel or iron.

Comment: Coin cutting was common enough that it entered American English - "Two bits" was slang for a US quarter dollar, and "four bits" slang for a half dollar. This slang is now archaic but was prevalent at least up to WWII (my father, born 1927, used it frequently). The Spanish real was legal tender in the US (along with a few other "reputable" foreign coins) until 1857, so it has a long history in this country.

Comment: @Jurp Then I suppose if you asked "How much is 8 bits?" in 1920, you'd probably be told "a dollar".  But ask the same question in 2020 and you'd probably be told "a byte". :)

Comment: @TimGoodman in the [late 1960s](https://jcmit.net/memoryprice.htm),  "How much is 8 bits?" --> about a dollar. ;-)

Comment: TIL why they’re actually called ‘pieces of eight’, which I’d vaguely wondered about ever since first seeing whichever of the _Pirates of the Caribbean_ films it is that uses them as a plot device.

Comment: They're called "pieces of eights" because "piece" is an old word for coin, and they are worth 8 reales. The name is unrelated to the fact that people cut them up.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The usual method was with a hammer and a [cold chisel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chisel#Cold_chisel). A large stone would suffice as an anvil. Coins are fairly small and thin, and the silver coins of the period were quite soft, as you can see from the wear on the example in your picture. 
A blacksmith would be able to do this easily, as would almost anyone with basic metal-working skills and tools. Blacksmiths were more common in period than today, of course, and a higher proportion of people would have owned the necessary tools.

The division of coins into halves, quarters and eighths follows naturally from cutting them by hand. It's much easier to cut things into successive halves with reasonable accuracy than it is to cut tenths.

Comment: I successfully [cut aluminium of comparable thickness](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/a/8016/319) with a wood chisel recently.  Soft precious metals should be even easier.  In fact hitting a sturdy knife ought do it

Comment: And having a cross design on one side provided convenient guidelines for cutting the coin into quarters.